# Export Alberta Oil Sands Information Portal data from ESRI MapServer

Tags: arcgis-server, geojson

I'm trying to get the Alberta Oil Sands outlines from https://maps.alberta.ca/genesis/rest/services/OSIP-Oilsands_Business_Data/Latest/MapServer

Until now I've tried the KML and KMZ export – both are empty. The JSON is ESRI JSON, which only contains metadata.

The [online view](https://maps.alberta.ca/genesis/rest/services/OSIP-Oilsands_Business_Data/Latest/MapServer?f=jsapi) and the [WMS](http://wms:https://maps.alberta.ca/genesis/services/OSIP-Oilsands_Business_Data/20180220/MapServer/WmsServer?FORMAT=image/jpeg&VERSION=1.1.1&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=0&STYLES=&SRS=%7Bproj%7D&WIDTH=%7Bwidth%7D&HEIGHT=%7Bheight%7D&BBOX=%7Bbbox%7D) work – but these are just SVG shapes (js) or JPG tiles (WMS).

I thought that this would open Alberta goverment data. If not: How can I trace the outline to GeoJSON?

Answer (score 1):

This service is composed of two layers. When you try to export it, it first assembles the layers and returns an image.

To get the individual features, you would need to go to each layer of interest.

From the page you sent, click on `ERCB Oilsands Deposits`. At the bottom, click on `query`. Now, you must specify a search condition... but since you want the entire layer, just put `1=1` as the `where` clause :-)  At last, at the bottom, don't forget to specify the `format` to be `json`.

Alternatively, you can search the Open Alberta portals, one of them being [GeoDiscover](https://geodiscover.alberta.ca/geoportal/catalog/main/home.page), which often offers to download Shapefiles, GeoJSON etc.

Comment: GeoDiscover (map viewer part) will only work in IE11 due to silverlight - Chrome/Firefox refuse to allow it to run.

Comment: @Mapperz to be honnest, I don't trust (nor use) the viewers of most open data portals. The displayed data is not always the same as the downloadable one... and even the downloadable data can be different between formats